# How to create 256 Posix Message Queue with each message having msg size of 8192 bytes

Tags: linux, posix, message-queue

---

***Trying to create posix message queue's with 256 number of message queue . And each message queue must have 100 msgs. Also, each message must be of 8192 bytes***

But, ulimit for Posix message queue is **819200 bytes**. So, i am unable to create message queue's.
Can anyone suggest any method or function logic to be able to create message queue's of above requirements. Also, if any command line's to set the ulimit Posix message queue size.
I had tried with **ulimit -q Some_value**, but didn't worked.
Can **setrlimit()** function will be able to modify posix message queue ulimit value?
Thanks.

Comment: "ulimit -q Some_value, but didn't worked" -- can you clarify what exactly you did and what happened?

Comment: run cmd "ulimit -q 81920000" in root directory, then checked for ulimit -q, it still shows default value i.e. 819200.

Comment: `ulimit` is not a program but a shell builtin. So, which shell are you using? Are you running that command in the same shell process or different ones? Please [edit] your question to include exact steps of what you did and what happened.

Comment: okk, let me try this way. working on multi thread program. In this to send & receive message between threads, i am using mq_send & mq_receive of posix message queue. Due to which, number of message queue created using mq_open are only 9 due to default values of mq_attr params. So , i am trying to increase message queue's by modifying posix message queue's ulimit size. so, can you be able to suggest something about this?

Comment: Please don't add clarifications as comments. Add them to your question! Still, "exact steps" (also see [mcve]) are missing.